# What is the intended behavior for client roles in Agora Web SDK?

Tags: agora.io

I am using the web SDK, in which setting the client role as `host` or `audience` seems to have no effect. I have tried setting it before and after joining the channel. Contrary to the behavior described in the Android SDK docs, where setting the role as audience makes Agora automatically unpublish the stream.

Also, `peer-online` event seems to fire only when a stream is published. To be very specific when `rtc.client.publish()` is called and not otherwise.
This is all on temp token generated on the console.
Is this intended behavior for the Web SDK ? Are we, devs, supposed to disable the stream using the stream spec object on client side if audience ?

Answer (score 0):

The two available roles are: `host` and `audience`. I think you may have used the role `client` in `setClientRole` which doesn't really exist.

You need to set the role just before joining the channel as per normal convention.

Check out these files for sample working code:

- [Broadcast client code - host](https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo/blob/master/js/agora-broadcast-client.js)
- [Broadcast audience code](https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo/blob/master/js/agora-audience-client.js)
- [Sample app](https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo)

The SDK triggers the `peer-online` callback under one of the following circumstances:

- A remote user/host joins the channel by calling the Client.join method.
- A remote user switches the user role to the host by calling the Client.setClientRole method after joining the channel.
- A remote user/host rejoins the channel after a network interruption.
- The host injects an online media stream into the channel by calling the Client.addInjectStreamUrl method.

Agora Documentation Link: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html

Comment: I havnt used the role "client" instead of the ones mentioned. Setting it on the web SDK seems to have no effect. 
The event "peer-online" seems to fire only when a stream is subscribed to and added. Does NOT fire when peer enters `.on('join)`
I am using a test environment.

Comment: Just to add more clarity, I noticed the peer online fires when .publish() is called by remote peer.